# How to specify relative path in 7-zip command line?

Tags: path, 7-zip

I like 7-zip and I needed it's command line today. I bumped into a problem.

Is there a way to specify a path **within** archive when compressing?

For example I have a file at `C:\some_dir\my_file.txt`.
When compressing I want to specify destination path to be `\other_dir\my_file.txt` within archive.

Is this possible? This seems like fairly common thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the 7zip utility, nor any archiver I know of supports this directly. You can, however, create a directory structure matching what you would like in the archive, copy files into place, and archive that instead... Quite sad, in any case, seeing functionality present in the GUI, yet missing on the command line.

Comment: I ran into a similar program recently and wondered... can it really be that the CLI doesn't support this? As far as I understood it, the GUI is just a front-end for the CLI... or isn't it?

Comment: The GUI might be taking the same approach, just using temp files... I know for the case of 7zip, the GUI can do this, while the CLI can not. That is to say, the GUI can directly rename and move files inside an archive.

Comment: I believe that both CLI and GUI use the same library rather than GUI talking to cli.

Comment: @Kugel, that sounds very likely. Alas, it's a shame.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 7zip's **'rn'** command on the command line:

```
7z rn archive.7z my_file.txt \other_dir\my_file.txt
```

This will put your already compressed file in different (internal) archive folder. This works only on already created archive.

If you need 'other_dir' to be some relative path (not random directory), you can play with the current **working directory** and pass **relative** file names to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

First create list file which contains the relative paths to the files to backup.
Than use that list file as input file preceded by "@"

```
7zip.exe a archive.7z @listfile.txt
```

ListFile should look like this:

```
doc\Text.txt
vid\movie.avi
```

I did not test this with wildcards though.
7zip version was 18.05

Comment: Sure, 7zip allows you to put your filenames in a separate "listfile". But it doesn't appear to have the ability to do what the original question wants, which is to have a different name on input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

1. First you define the root directory relative to which you will create the list of files (for example, C:\RootDir).
2. Next, you create a list of files to be archived, with paths relative to the root directory defined (in step 1).
3. Save the list of files in a separate file, for example, in D:\list.txt.
4. Switch to the root directory (using the DOS command cd C:\RootDir)
5. Run the command:
   C:\RootDir> "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7zip.exe" a -tzip d:\out .zip @"D:\list.txt" -scsWIN

It's all. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).